# Converting Silverlight app to HTML? Suggestions please

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, winforms, silverlight

We have an E-Commerce site that allows users to buy products, view their shopping basket etc. It is written in Silverlight. Unfortunately many users refuse to install it, or have an iPad and hate Microsoft etc. Should we make a HTML version? I've done plenty of WinForms work in the past. It would look pretty crappy compared to the Silverlight version.

Maybe I should try and use a lot of AJAX? Then I might be able to re-use the existing Silverlight Web Service more easily.

And what's all this fuss about MVC? I haven't tried this yet. Maybe now is the time?

So many options... Any suggestions on appropriate technology and architecture would be much appreciated. The aim is to do this with minimum work :)

I should also add that this site is sold as a product to our customers. That means whatever technology I use should easily support multiple skins and even customized behavior.

Cheers
Mark

Comment: you can probably get a lot of silverlight-ese out of html5. depends what ipad supports. also depends if your users also hate google/mozilla/etc. as their browsers aren't 100% html5 compliant. go microsoft, go ie9!

Comment: Rewriting the website is going to take time and money. Will the increased sales from the Silverlight haters and iPad fanboys give you a return on your investment?

Comment: @Otaku IE has been pain for developers for a long time now. its nice knowing that IE9 is html5 compliant

Comment: Yikes you ended up actually developing a E-commerce system in Silverlight, how did that happen?  One needs to do more research.  For example some are suggesting HTML5, so some questions for research would be, how many potential customers don't use a HTML5 capable browser?  When a standard is not yet ratified can anything actually be said to be compliant?  What are the cross-browser risks of attempting HTML5 delivery while the "standard" is still in some flux?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest trying out MVC and building a ASP .NET website.  It will be much easier to port a silverlight application to an ASP application since they both run on the .NET framework.  Your users will not need to install anything funky, and for fancier things, you can use javascript (Personally, I like to use the JQuery library).  Best of all, the language (C# or VB) will be the same!

If you built your Silverlight app using the MVVM pattern (a lot of silverlight apps use this pattern), you will be able to see the similarities to an MVC pattern (Model View Controller).  Also, if you have a web service already, it should be easy to reuse it with an ASP website.

HTML5 might be a little too soon for most customers, especially if they use a browser that is not ie9.  It will also be more work to convert it, especially if you are using a database, which i assume you are.  That's the beauty of moving to ASP; it will most likely be pretty simple to reuse most of your code.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Chad. I'm still trying to figure out the best approach.

Comment: What about any tool/utility to convert the Silverlight screen to MVC view?